# why the enter command output is M in CentOS 7.x

Tags: linux

Today when I using this command to generate a rsa key in my CentOS 7.x, when I using enter to confirm my command, but the output is `^M`, what's happening?

```
[root@izbp19pke6x0v6ruecuy1yz ~]# ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C jiangtingqiang@gmail.com
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa): ^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^C
[root@izbp19pke6x0v6ruecuy1yz ~]# ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C jiangtingqiang@gmail.com
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa): github-actions^C
[root@izbp19pke6x0v6ruecuy1yz ~]# ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C jiangtingqiang@gmail.com
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa): ^M^M^M^M^C
```

why would this happen and what should I do to fix it? This is the tty config:

```
[root@izbp19pke6x0v6ruecuy1yz ~]# stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 37; columns 210; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = M-^?; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc ixany imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

I have never encount this problem before. And now I have no clue about this problem. any idea is welcome bro..., by the way, my local OS is Mac OS Catalina, I am using zsh, the terminal tool is iTerm.

Comment: This is most likely a character encoding mismatch issue. Your terminal is sending the `^M` as carriage return but CentOS is not interpreting it correctly. Check your macOS terminal app settings and see if anything is amiss.

Comment: Are you using SSH to connect to the CentOS box, or are you running CentOS in a virtual machine?

Comment: I am using ssh to connect CentOS, the cloud CentOS should be KVM virtual machine. My local machine is not virtual machine. @chepner

Comment: you might get better responses on [unix.se]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's normal for terminals to send `CR` (`^M`) upon <kbd>Enter</kbd>. They don't have to send `LF` (`^J`). In my Debian, Kubuntu, in few other Linux systems <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> shows `^M`. I would say `^M` (not `^J`) is the correct (or at least [common](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253293/108618)) character for line ending coming from the terminal.

Some shells accept both `^M` and `^J` to run the typed command. Bash does, Zsh does.

Apparently `ssh-keygen` needs `^J` and it's OK because it should expect and get `^J`. Trivia: when `ssh-keygen` ([or almost anything](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/367086/108618)) runs, the terminal is not in the [raw mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21760/108618) and the program gets nothing until `^J` comes.

Without changing any settings you can generate `^J` "manually" by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>. If you use this combination instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd> while providing input for `ssh-keygen` then it will work.

In my systems (where <kbd>Enter</kbd> sends `^M`) `ssh-keygen` works because the respective terminal driver in each system translates `^M` into `^J` on the fly. A terminal driver does this when `icrnl` is set. It's normal to have a terminal that sends `^M` upon <kbd>Enter</kbd> and a terminal driver that translates it to `^J` on its end.

Your terminal apparently sends `^M` but in the output of `stty -a` there is `-icrnl` which means the terminal driver in question does not translate `^M` to `^J`.

Either configure your terminal (`iterm`, PuTTY, `konsole` or whatever) to send `^J` upon <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or use

```
stty icrnl
```

to make the terminal driver translate `^M` into `^J` expected by `ssh-keygen`.

Answer (score 2):

Not a solution, but the `^M` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>) character is [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) for the unprintable character Carriage Return (`CR`) as noted in this [Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/763879/why-are-special-characters-such-as-carriage-return-represented-as-m).

Normally, Line Feed (`LF`) is used as the new line character in Unix based systems like Linux. If I am not misreading your TTY config, it appears `CR` may be being sent instead of `LF`. So it seems plausible that the on-screen terminal is printing the caret notation in place of recognizing it as a proper line ending or whatever.

As to "why" this is happening, I believe `CR` was used in the past on MacOS as the new line character but current versions of MacOS no longer use it (they have switched to `LF` as I understand it).

Assuming this is the issue, my thought would be to perhaps investigate changing your TTY config to send the "correct" character `LF` (`^J` based on this [Wikipedia chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart)) in place of `CR`.